# Python: Inserting a vector into a matrix

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, vector

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.zeros([4,N])
x[:,0]= np.vstack([1000,0,0,50])
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4,1) into shape (4)
```

I'm quite confused as to why this isn't working, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x[:,0]= np.array([1000,0,0,50]).T
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the way slicing works in numpy as `x[:,0]` in your case expects an array not a vector.

The correct way to achieve what you want is:

```
import np as numpy
x = np.zeros([4,N])
x[:,0]= np.array([1000,0,0,50])
```